# Docker container Ubuntu 16.04 No directory, logging in with HOME=/ mysql fail to start

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to configure a docker image for web development, so i can use in my Dockerfile. I installed mysql-server, and ran service start mysql, where i encounter this error **No directory, logging in with HOME=/** from mysql and also with the [fail] tags. I did my research around the web but i did not find much help.

Comment: take a look at https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/

Comment: But for me to use laravel, i need to install mysql in the image i'm building. Otherwise i will be pulling from multiple images in the Dockerfile and i'm trying to prevent that. @gaetano

Comment: What's wrong with pulling multiple images?

Comment: According to the research from this morning, its not possible to chain multiple images into one container, here is the reference,https://abdelrahmanhosny.com/2015/07/11/how-to-merge-two-docker-images/ . I'm new to Docker and trying to automate a few processes, the idea is to have a container to run composer, laravel and mysql with ease. @matino

Comment: I got this problem as well.